# C output byte size

Tags: c

pretty simple question regarding my C output.

This is my code:

```
struct test {
  int a;
  int b;
  char c[30];
};

int main() {
  // Write C code here
  struct test bob = {1, 2, "hello"};
  printf("%d ", sizeof(bob.c));
  printf("%d ", sizeof(bob.a));
  printf("%d", sizeof(bob.b));
  printf("%d ", sizeof(struct test));
  printf("%d ", sizeof(bob));
  return 0;
}
```

The output is 30 4 440 40. Why is the last number 40 and not 38? It would also help if you can explain the math working for how the program calculates each printf.

I tried asking my friends too but everyone thinks it's 38 bytes.

Comment: There's no space after this one. `printf("%d", sizeof(bob.b));` [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing) explains why.

Comment: Sidenote: The correct format specifier for `size_t` arguments is `%zu`, not `%d`